# How to perform 'sendKeys' or any keyboard interaction mechanism in a smartwatch(WearOS) through Appium?

Tags: android, appium, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, wearables

I was trying to automate a scenario using Appium, where User will enter something in 'Google Keeps' app installed in a smartwatch (WearOS), which will be synced and validated in 'Google keeps' app installed in a smartphone.

While I was trying to enter  something into the smartwatch version of the 'Google Keeps', I can see that no element can be found by using Appium Inspector to perform a 'sendKeys' operation.  I have observed that, when you're trying to type something in a smartwatch, GBoard occupies the whole screen and it doesn't allow the element to interact with the AppiumDriver. So, in that case, how can you perform 'sendKeys' operation on a smartwatch?
P.S.: I know how to press keys by using co-ordinates, but I'm looking for a more stable and permanent solution for this. Attaching a picture of the current problem.[image: seetheimage]

Comment: Have you tried using the .sendKeys to the specific @AndroidFindBy/MobileElement you have identified and want the keys send to?

Comment: Yeah, normally that works in 'Mobile' as you can identify the element on which you want to perform sendKeys, but in SmartWatch(WearOS), the whole screen is blocked by the GBoard which also blocks the element on which you want to pass the sendkeys.

Comment: have you tried driver.hideKeyboard(); first and then sendKeys to MobileElement?